# PHP:HTML Do Pre-filled form values get overriden?

Tags: php, html

If in a form i set

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'entry' value ='default_text'/>
```

And a user enters `'foo'` in place of `'default_text'` is this enough to make `$_POST['entry']` become `'foo'` instead of `'default_text'`?

If not how do i make that happen?

Comment: Have you tried it rather then just asking blindly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone enters text into this input:

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'entry' value ='default_text'/>
```

PHP will receive the new text in $_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST etc. and not the default (so, to answer your question, yes that is enough).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the `<input type="text" />` element is placed within a `<form method="post">` element which also contains an `<input type="submit" />` element to send the data:

```
<form method="post" action="/url/where/form/will/be/sent.php">
    <input type = 'text' name = 'entry' value ='default_text'/>
    <input type = 'submit' />
</form>
```

Of course, data will only be sent when the form is submitted. What happened wrong in your code?